# Flickr app with jsonp in Vue 'Cannot set property 'data' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jsonp

I'm at the beginning of making a simple one page photo steam app with the public Flickr stream, but with what i've done so far i'm getting the error

> 'Cannot set property 'data' of undefined'.

My code:

```
 <b-container>
    <b-row>
      <b-col>
      <p md="4" v-for="photo in Photos">{{photo.id}}</p>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
    import jsonp from "jsonp";

export default {
    name: 'PhotoFeed',
    data: function() {
        return {
            Photos: [],
            apiURL: "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json"
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getFlickrFeed();
    },
    methods: {
        getFlickrFeed(){
            let jsonp = require('jsonp');

            jsonp(this.apiURL, {name:'jsonFlickrFeed'}, function(err,data) {
                this.data = data;
                var self = this;
                if (err){
                    console.log(err.message);
                }
                else {
                    this.Photos = self.data;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `var self = this` to be outside the anonymous function definition so `this` keyword is not shadowed by the new function;

```
getFlickrFeed () {
    let jsonp = require('jsonp');
    var self = this;     // now self refers to the vue component and can
    // access the Photos property in data

    jsonp(this.apiURL, { name:'jsonFlickrFeed' }, function (err,data) {

        if (err){
            console.log(err.message);
        }
        else {
            // also use self.Photos to refer to the Vue component
            self.Photos = data;
        }
    });
}
```

The simplest is to use an arrow function instead of an anonymous function:

```
jsonp(this.apiURL, { name:'jsonFlickrFeed' }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    else {
        this.Photos = data;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use arrow function `()=>` and use `this` in the callback context as follows :

```
           jsonp(this.apiURL, {name:'jsonFlickrFeed'}, (err,data)=> {
            this.data = data;
            if (err){
                console.log(err.message);
            }
            else {
                this.Photos = this.data;
            }
        });
```